# Only Getting Half a Barcode from TCP/IP Barcode Reader

Tags: c#, barcode, tcpclient, networkstream, tcp

I have a Microscan TCP/IP barcode reader. I am currently using the following code to connect to it and retrieve a barcode when read:

```
// responseData string will be the barcode received from reader
string responseData = null;

TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.90.10.36", 2001);

// The "getData" is just a generic string to initiate connection
Byte[] sentData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("getData");
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
Byte[] receivedData = new Byte[20];
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
{
    responseData += Convert.ToChar(receivedData[i]);
}

// Closes the socket connection.
client.Close();
```

The issue that I am having is that I am only getting 10 characters when the barcode is 15. Everything works correctly until the `Int32 bytes = stream.Read(receivedData, 0 receivedData.Length);` line. The `Read` call is returning 10 rather than 15 as it should be. I have tried modifying the code in a few different ways, but all of them have just returned 10 characters like normal. This works correctly if the barcode is 10 characters or fewer, but not if more.

I don't think it's an issue with the scanner, but I am checking into that as well. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Got a link to the scanner's API?  I googled and found a document but it doesn't seem to be the right one because it didn't support any "getData" option.

Comment: I actually haven't seen an API for the scanner. The "getData" string that I send is just something generic, as the scanner needs some type of data to be sent to initiate a connection with the client, and any string will work.

Comment: Are the 10 characters that you are getting verified as the first 10 in the bar code?  Maybe you're not getting bar code data but something else, error code perhaps?

Comment: Yes, they are always the first 10 characters of the barcode. Also, when scanning a barcode with less than 10 characters, the barcode matches that length and is not at a fixed length of 10.

Comment: Try doing a second `Int32 bytes2 = stream.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);` after the first one (perhaps with a `Thread.Sleep(1500)`; before) and see if there is some other data.

Comment: @xanatos has a good idea.  The writer might be writing in 10 byte chunks and you read the first chunk.

Comment: This is certainly interesting. When I add the second read, it does get the entire barcode. If I add a sleep, it for some reason adds newline characters, and without a sleep it does not. Is there a cleaner solution than just using two reads?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
// responseData string will be the barcode received from reader
string responseData = null;

using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.90.10.36", 2001))
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        byte[] sentData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("getData");
        stream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int bytes;

        while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            {
                responseData += (char)buffer[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `while` cycle will repeat itself while there are new characters that can be received. I have even put some `using` around your code (it's better to use them instead of `Close`ing manually objects)

Comment: Hmmm. For some reason it seems like I am getting stuck inside of a loop somewhere. It goes through the while loop a couple of times and then gets stuck in the for loop I think.

Comment: @danielu13 Perhaps it's receiving only new lines? Try looking at the responseData after each passing.

Comment: It's getting the entire string into `responseData`, and I now think it is getting out of the entire while loop. It's just not getting to my return statement, but the only thing before the return are the ends of the usings.